# Add Padding to PushButton for PyQt5 in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, padding

I'd like to know how to add padding with respect to left, right, top and bottom edges of the PyQt window in python. I have found code for this in C++, But i haven't been able to make it work in python. Please Help me fix it.

I am using this code:

```
quit_button.setStyleSheet("padding:200px")
```

Unfortunately, does not seem to work, and it pushes the button to the top left corner of the window, and does not seem to move even when i change the padding pixels.

Note: I have tried using `quit_button.setStyleSheet("padding-left:200px")` and similarly `padding-right`,  but all it does is makes the button label disappear.

End goal: I want the exit button to be on the right bottom edge of the window. But when i resize it, it should remain at the right bottom edge and not stay stagnant at it's place while the window resizes. In other words, I want it to behave like 'normal' windows applications behave.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: when you use padding with qss refers to the text of the button with respect to the edge of the button, it is not about the window, it could clearly explain what you want to obtain.

Comment: Okay. Makes sense then. How do i pad the button with respect to the window? I don't really want to 'move' it to a certain location because on resizing, the button does not move with the window. I want it to move with the resized window. How do i achieve that?

Comment: if so, the padding will increase, do you want the button to always be in the center of the window?

Comment: No. I want the exit button to be on the right bottom edge of the window. But when i resize it, it should remain at the right bottom edge and not stay stagnant at it's place while the window resizes. In other words, I want it to behave like 'normal' windows applications behave.

Comment: okay, that's what you should indicate in your question, add that detail in your question. I also recommend publishing a [mcve], I'll post an answer but this will be a general case, however if you publish an appropriate code I could customize the response.

Comment: Thank you. I'll update the question then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164635/discussion-between-animikh-aich-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: When should there be pixels between the bottom of the widget and the button, and the same with the right part of the window?

Comment: Yes, Say 20 pixels padding from both the right and the bottom edge to the button would do.

Comment: Try with my answer

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to overwrite the `resizeEvent()` method and set the new button position

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(200, 200)
        self.quit_button = QPushButton("Quit", self)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        p = self.rect().bottomRight()-QPoint(20, 20) - self.quit_button.rect().bottomRight()
        self.quit_button.move(p)
        QWidget.resizeEvent(self, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```